# Mac Terminal - Rename Keeping Last 6 Characters

Tags: terminal, macos

I'm using the built in Terminal, and I am totally new to this coding so I will need to know exactly what to type when I open the Terminal. Also, please don't direct me to any other software. So lets say...

- I have a folder named "Power" on my Desktop (without the quotation marks around it of course).
- In that folder there are multiple .tif files named like the following:

  - Washington,George-150987.tif
  - Lincoln,Abraham-755103.tif
  - Smith,Jack & Jill-102347.tif
  - Jones-Newman,Martha & John Newman-137881.tif
- These names have one thing in common. They all have a 6 digit number before the extension, and always will.
- I want a way to batch rename a large group of these files keeping just the last 6 digits. Hell, if there's a code that could rename keeping just numbers, that would be THE BEST, because in rare occasions, there might be a

  Smith,Jane-108965(mrs).tif

But if there is no code for that, that's fine, I can use another software to get rid of that (mrs) in a second.

Comment: Just a small nitpick for your learnings, it would not be called `code` but `command`, which can be combined into a `script`. Since you are using  preexisting applications and utilities

Answer (score 6):

**Make a backup of the files first!**

Then open Terminal (, start a `bash` shell if you are not using the default shell) and run

```
cd ~/Desktop/Power
\ls | while IFS= read f; do echo mv -vn "$f" "${f/*-/}"; done
```

This will *not* rename anything but just show how each file will get renamed. If the output looks ok, run

```
\ls | while IFS= read f; do mv -vn "$f" "${f/*-/}"; done
```

PS: This assumes that the only `-` in the file names is the one right before the number.

---

Some explanations about what's going on here:

- `\ls` lists all files, the `\` ensures that no alias expansion takes place. The output is fed into a pipe but we do not need to worry about multi-column output because `ls` in these cases automatically assumes `-1`
- `while ... do; ...; done` loops over all lines/files
- `IFS= read f` reads a file name from standard input into `$f`. The `IFS=` ensures that none of the characters on standard input confuses `read` into expecting two values instead of one (technically this is probably not required here, but it's good practice anyway)
- `${f/*-/}` does string substitution on the value of `$f`, in this case replacing everything up to and including the `-` with the empty string. See `man bash` (Parameter Expansion) for details.